# Joining pivoted tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have been advised to use the pivot for SQL Server and it is working with this code

```
select 
    cs.DateAdded as 'Date', cs.Invoice, cu.StoreName as 'Store', 
    cu.AccountName as 'Customer', cu.StoreAddress as 'Address',
    SUM(Case cs.ProductId WHEN '2' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '700',
    SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '700 Amount',
    SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '1' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '350',
    SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '350 Amount',
    SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '3' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '1L',
    SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '1L Amount'
from 
    ConsignmentSale cs
left join 
    Customer cu on cs.CustomerId=cu.CustomerId
group by 
    cs.Invoice, cs.CustomerId, cu.AccountName, cu.StoreAddress, 
    cs.DateAdded, cu.StoreName
```

This is somewhat static because if we get another product, then I would have to add the corresponding product Id. It's alright for now. But my real concern here is; this statement is only for a `ConsignmentSale` table. I have a `CashSale` table that have the same structure or fields as the `ConsignmentSale` table so I can just use the same code as above and change the `from ConsignmentSale` to `from CashSale`.

However, the problem is, how can I join the two tables so I would get all the results and just have a column that indicates if it a 'Consignment' or 'Cash'? I know that I would need the join table somehow but I don't know where to join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to union the tables into one virtual table and apply your pivot on that result.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    select 
        TableType=1,--INDICATES CONSIGNMENT
        cs.DateAdded as 'Date', cs.Invoice, cu.StoreName as 'Store', 
        SUM(Case cs.ProductId WHEN '2' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '700',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '700 Amount', 
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '1' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '350',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '350 Amount',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '3' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '1L',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '1L Amount'
from 
        ConsignmentSale cs
        left join Customer cu on cs.CustomerId=cu.CustomerId

UNION ALL

    select 
        TableType=2,--INDICATES CASH
        cs.DateAdded as 'Date', cs.Invoice, cu.StoreName as 'Store', 
        SUM(Case cs.ProductId WHEN '2' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '700',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '700 Amount', 
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '1' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '350',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '350 Amount',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '3' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as '1L',
        SUM(case cs.ProductId WHEN '3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as '1L Amount'
from 
        Cash cs
        left join Customer cu on cs.CustomerId=cu.CustomerId
)AS Detail
group by Detail.Invoice, Detail.CustomerId, Detail.AccountName, Detail.StoreAddress, Detail.DateAdded, Detail.StoreName
```

Comment: Yeah! That's it! Thanks!